# How to repeat loop n times in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have below scenario like:

```
if [file exists]; then
   exit   
elif
   recheck if file exist (max 10 times)
   if found exit else recheck again as per counter  
fi
```

Comment: This is a very basic feature in shells. Did you even research it?

Comment: Yes. But not getting expected output from my code. Also want to write as abbreviated as possible

Comment: @Peschke, well, they'd need at least what, three basic features (loops, conditionals, testing the file, breaking out of a loop). At least the question is quite clear as it is. Though it could contain a sketch of what Rocky tried, but then someone would rewrite it full in the answers anyway. ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are many ways to do this loop.

With `ksh93` syntax (also supported by `zsh` and `bash`):

```
for (( i=0; i<10; ++i)); do
    [ -e filename ] && break
    sleep 10
done
```

For any POSIX-like shell:

```
n=0
while [ "$n" -lt 10 ] && [ ! -e filename ]; do
    n=$(( n + 1 ))
    sleep 10
done
```

Both of the loops sleep 10 seconds in each iteration before testing the existence of the file again.

After the loop has finished, you will have to test for existence of the file a last time to figure out whether the loop exited due to running 10 times or due to the file appearing.

If you wish, and if you have access to inotify-tools, you may replace the `sleep 10` call with

```
inotifywait -q -t 10 -e create ./ >/dev/null
```

This would wait for a file creation event to occur in the current directory, but would time out after 10 seconds.  This way your loop would exit as soon as the given filename appeared (if it appeared).

The full code, with `inotifywait` (replace with `sleep 10` if you don't want that), may look like

```
for (( i=0; i<10; ++i)); do
    [ -e filename ] && break
    inotifywait -q -t 10 -e create ./ >/dev/null
done

if [ -e filename ]; then
    echo 'file appeared!'
else
    echo 'file did not turn up in time'
fi
```

Comment: With inotify, you could almost replace the whole loop. Just test if the file is there, and if not, inotifywait for a 100 seconds. Almost, since the file could be created _just_ between the test and the inotify, and you'd sleep for the full 100 seconds before timing out...

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, that's a good idea, but here I'm just using `inotifywait` as a drop-in replacement for `sleep`.

Answer (score 42):

If the count is not a variable you can use brace expansion:

```
for i in {1..10}   # you can also use {0..9}
do
  whatever
done
```

If the count is a variable you can use the `seq` command:

```
count=10
for i in $(seq $count)
do
  whatever
done
```

Comment: I want to loop only if file is not found (max. 10 times). If found lets say 3rd time then exit successfully

Comment: @Rocky86 : This does not contradict the solution proposed by xenoid. Nobody forces you to count until the end ....

Comment: I like this one `$(seq $count)`

Comment: `seq` is only for old bash. `{1..10}` is for current (like last 10 years plus) bash

Comment: @mikemaccana They aren't the same, you cannot use the brace expansion form with variables.

Comment: That's true, I mean you don't need to use `seq(1, 10)` (which is  the most common variant in current bash.

Answer (score -1):

```
n=0
until [ "$((n+=1))" -gt 10 ]
do    <exists? command exit
done
echo oh noes!
```

though `test -e file && exit` is more flexible

Comment: Why the question mark? Note that the behaviour for globs in the target of redirections varies between shells.

Comment: Note that it has the side effect of opening the file, which for fifos for instance can be quite bad (worse with a symlink to /dev/watchdog on Linux for instance)

Comment: Even in Bash, where this would look for a file like `exists1` or such, it still prints a bunch of errors if/when a matching file isn't found. (Also it errors if there are multiple matches.) Any other shell I tested seems to give errors in any case...

Comment: @ikkachu - yeah. that was kinda the point. if the error happens, the script reports. if stderr should be suppressed, suppress it `done 2<>/dev/null`. does `bash` does that scripted? i thought it only effed that up in an `-i`nteractive context. still, *`exists?`* is as much as a filler name as *`file`*. but yeah, i ***hate*** quoting in redirects - if screws ***so***  much up.

Comment: @Stéphane - no reason, really. but yeah, fifos, unreadables... thats why i noted `test -e`.

Comment: @mikeserv, it doesn't do that if you specify `-o posix`. But if Bash's default behaviour is effing it up, then note that zsh effs it even worse. Though I can't see why quoting the target of a redirection would screw anything up? In the same way as in most other contexts, it unambiguously disables splitting and filename expansion, so why not use it here if you want to have a filename with a space or `?` or such?

Comment: anyway, in the context of the question, if they explicitly want to give file multiple chances to appear, then it seems weird to assume that it should be considered an error on every test if it doesn't exist...

Comment: @ikkachu - `zsh` doesnt claim to be a posix shell.